# Check syntax return true or false, jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery for validate, and I want to check my syntax.
Here my syntax:

```
$("#username").focusout(function() {
            var name = $("#username").val();
            if (name == "") {
                $("#validuser").removeClass("alert-box info radius");
                $("#validuser").html("Please insert your name").addClass("alert-box alert").fadeIn("slow");
                return false;
            } else if (contains(name, names) == true) {
                $("#validuser").removeClass("alert-box info radius");
                $("#validuser").html("Name has been taken, choose another Name").addClass("alert-box alert").fadeIn("slow");
                return false;
            } else {
                $("#validuser").removeClass("alert-box alert round");
                $("#validuser").html("Your Name Correctly").addClass("alert-box info radius").css("display", "block");
            }
        });
```

My app still run, but i don't know my `$("#username").focusout(function() {..}` will return true or false. So, please! tell me how to check this with console.log or something else :)

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dkvjxdg3/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#username").focusout(function() {
        var name = $("#username").val();
        var result = null;
        if (name == "") {
            $("#validuser").removeClass("alert-box info radius");
            $("#validuser").html("Please insert your name").addClass("alert-box alert").fadeIn("slow");
            result = false;

        } else if (contains(name, names) == true) {
            $("#validuser").removeClass("alert-box info radius");
            $("#validuser").html("Name has been taken, choose another Name").addClass("alert-box alert").fadeIn("slow");
            result = false;
        } else {
            $("#validuser").removeClass("alert-box alert round");
            $("#validuser").html("Your Name Correctly").addClass("alert-box info radius").css("display", "block");
            result = false;
        }
        alert(result);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dkvjxdg3/1/[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkvjxdg3/1/)